# How to raise dependency property every time whenever any value is assigned

Tags: wpf

How to raise dependency property every time whenever any value is assigned.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What do you mean by "raise dependency property"? Every time a value is assigned to what?

Comment: yeah... property change event gets triggered on dependency property whenever it is set, even if value is not changed

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:  How can we ensure that the PropertyChanged event gets triggered on a dependency property when the property is set, even if the property value hasn't actually changed?

Maybe this other question will help...

[WPF dependency property setter not firing when PropertyChanged is fired, but source value is not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728267/wpf-dependency-property-setter-not-firing-when-propertychanged-is-fired-but-sour)

Comment: This should be a comment... (Unless you answer your question, too ;) )

Comment: yeah... property change event should get triggered on dependency property whenever it is set, even if value is not changed